# Converting a raw query to Laravel query builder

Tags: laravel

I have the following MySQL query which fetches a list of the last 9 authors to write a post and lists them in order of the date of the last post they wrote.

It's working properly but I'd like to re-write it using the Laravel Query Builder. Here is the query at the moment:

```
    $authors = DB::select("
        SELECT 
            `a`.`id`, 
            `a`.`name`, 
            `a`.`avatar`, 
            `a`.`slug` AS `author_slug`, 
            `p`.`subheading`, 
            `p`.`title`, 
            `p`.`slug` AS `post_slug`, 
            `p`.`summary`, 
            `p`.`published_at`
        FROM 
            `authors` AS `a`
        JOIN 
            `posts` AS `p`
             ON `p`.`id` =
              (
                 SELECT `p2`.`id`
                 FROM `posts` AS `p2`
                 WHERE `p2`.`author_id` = `a`.`id`
                 ORDER BY `p2`.`published_at` DESC
                 LIMIT 1
              )
        WHERE 
            `a`.`online` = 1
        ORDER BY 
            `published_at` DESC
        LIMIT 9
    ");
```

I understand the basics of using the query builder, but there doesn't appear to be anything in the Laravel docs that allows for me to `JOIN` a table `ON` a `SELECT`.

Can anyone suggest a way that I can write this query using the Laravel Query builder, or perhaps suggest a way that I can rewrite this query to make it easier to structure with the query builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this

```
    $data = DB::table('authors')
        ->select(
            'a.id',
            'a.name',
            'a.avatar',
            'a.slug AS author_slug',
            'p.subheading',
            'p.title',
            'p.slug AS post_slug',
            'p.summary',
            p.published_at')
        ->from('authors AS a')
        ->join('posts AS p', 'p.id', '=', DB::raw("
            (
                SELECT p2.id FROM posts AS p2 
                WHERE p2.author_id = b.id 
                ORDER BY p2.published_at 
                DESC LIMIT 1
            )"))
        ->where('a.online', 1)
        ->limit(9)
        ->orderBy('p.published_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, @Komal. Your reply gave me the right idea to solve this. There are a few little mistakes in your answer, though. Do you mind if I edit them first before I mark the answer as correct?